# Select data from SQL database and display in table does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I don't understand why this isn't working, I have been stuck on this for ages and tried lots of different alternatives, but it just doesn't print the data from the database.

At the moment I am just trying to get the id to print, but eventually I want to print most of the data in the database (not including the hash).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Staroids Leaderboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border=1px>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>score</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "password");
            if (!$connect) {
                die(mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("staroids");
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM scores");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
            $name = $row['id']
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo '$name'?></td>

                </tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The image below shows what it looks like in html:

[image]

This image shows the database in local host and as you can see there is lots of data, but none of the names seem to print?!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct your syntax where it could be

```
$name = $row['id'];   //Put ; here
<?php echo $name;?>   //Remove quotes and put ;
```

Select name from DB and you can get name then.It should be

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM scores");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
?>
   <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
```

And dont use `mysql_*` functions due to they are deprecated.Instead use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` statements.

And as @Nedstark said use `try die(mysql_error());` for the errors regarding the mysql errors.

Comment: And definitely it shouldn't be `mysql_*` as its deprecated.

Comment: Nope, still outputs nothing :(

Comment: I have change them all to mysqli_... and it still isn't working

Comment: try die(mysql_error()); .It will print any mysql error if any

Comment: Cheers, solved my problem! I will accept the answer in 6 minutes

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><?php echo $name;?></td>
```

or use

```
 <td><?php echo "$name";?></td>  <!--(Bad idea but works)->
```

Variables work in double quotes("") not in  single quotes('')

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
    session_start();
   if (!(isset($_SESSION['UserName'])))
    {
      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Unauthorize user are redirected to Login page');".
  header('Location:http://localhost/campus');

  }

  include_once "connect.php";
  $find = mysql_query("YOUR SELECT STATEMENT ") or die('error');
  ob_start();
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>   
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>ST. MICHAEL's COLLEGE ILIGAN CITY</title> 
    <style>
        AlignJst  {
                    text-align:justify;
                    text-justify:inter-word;
                  }

         pTable   {
                    margin:2cm 4cm 3cm 4cm;
                  }

        body {color: black; font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, non-serif;}
        a:link {color: #FF8C00;} 
        a:visited {color: #FF8C00;}
        a:hover {color: #FF8C00; background: #ADD8E6; text-decoration:none;}
        a:active {color: #FF0000;}
        p {line-height: 2em;
            font-size:85%;
            color:black;
            letter-spacing: 0.3em
          }

       h1 {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12pt;
            color: navy;
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 3px;
          }

    </style>

    </head>
<body>
                      <?php

                                                     echo "<CENTER>"."<H1>TABLE TITLE</H>" . "<BR />";
                                                     echo "<H1>SUBTITLE</H>"."</CENTER>"."<BR/>";

                                                     echo "<CENTER>"."<p>"."<b>" . "PAST MORNING PRAYER SCHEDULE" ."</b>"."</p>"."</CENTER>"."<BR/>";
                                                     echo "<table border='1' width='100%' align ='center'>";
                                                     echo "<tr>";
                                                              echo "<th>SPONSOR NAME</th>";
                                                              echo "<th>VENUE </th>";
                                                              echo "<th>DATE EVENT</th>";
                                                              echo "<th>TIME </th>";

                                                           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find)){
                                                              echo "<tr>";
                                                              echo "<td>".$row['sponsor_name']."</td>";
                                                              echo "<td>".$row['Venue']."</td>";
                                                              echo "<td>".$row['Date_Event']."</td>";
                                                               echo "<td>".$row['Time_Event']."</td>";

                                                              echo "</tr>";
                                                                            }
                                                            echo "</table>";
                                                            echo "<br />". "<br />" ."<br />";
                                                            echo "<p align = 'right'>"."Prepared By:" . $_SESSION['UserName'] ."</p>";
                                                        ?>



</body>
```

Comment: try that one just change everything to your table value

Answer (score 0):

Other than changing mysql ==> msqli, I'd recommend a couple of debug strategies, in this case I would:

- fix the echo, you need to pick one of those two options:

  ```
  <?php echo $variable; ?>
  <?php echo "this is my variable {$variable}"; ?>
  ```

If you put a single quote PHP don't parse the content of what is about to print, it just print it as text, so what you have should print $name in the HTML...but, since I don't see any $name text in the black screenshot I think you might even not get into that loop...

- a good debug strategy would be to query for something broader, i.e. "SELECT * FROM `scores`", then you can do a

  ```
  <?php print_r($row); ?>
  ```

right after *while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {*